# Conditional Formatting - Highlight every cell that doesn't match in two rows, then move to next two rows

Tags: excel-formula

I have two worksheets that I'm trying to compare and then highlight every cell that is different between the two.  I've cut/pasted all the rows into one worksheet and highlighted the ones from the original spreadsheet.  It's easy visually to see the differences, but I'm trying to use conditional formatting to highlight just the rows that are different. I only want to check the first two rows for differences, then move to the next two rows checking for differences, then move to the next two rows.

```
Worksheet1 
1 Brown, Jean 100 Main St Richmond VA This is a long note about this contact. 12/14/2014 Yes 
Worksheet2 
1 Brown, Jean S. 101 Main St Richmond VA This is a long note about this contact. 12/14/2015 No 
Worksheet1 
2 Tomas, Bill 2500 Sky Cir Charlottesville CA This is a long note about this contact. 12/15/2014 No 
Worksheet2 
2 Tomas, Bill 2500 Sky Cir Charlottesville VA This is a long note about this contact. I added some to it. 12/15/2014 No
```

Every time I try to do it, it just checks each cell against the previous cell.  I just want to compare the first two rows, then compare the next two rows, etc. I need to attach this to an affidavit showing what changes I made to the worksheet, and I don't want to rely on my eyeballing each row and manually highlighting the differences.  Our IT group tried a special Compare software, but the result was a very difficult to read PDF file with lots of little pop-up comments that you have to hover over to see the differences.

Comment: Can you add a sample of your data please?

Comment: Worksheet1 1 Brown, Jean 100 Main St Richmond VA This is a long note about this contact. 12/14/2014 Yes
Worksheet2 1 Brown, Jean S. 101 Main St Richmond VA This is a long note about this contact. 12/14/2015 No
Worksheet1 2 Tomas, Bill 2500 Sky Cir Charlottesville CA This is a long note about this contact. 12/15/2014 No
Worksheet2 2 Tomas, Bill 2500 Sky Cir Charlottesville VA This is a long note about this contact. I added some to it. 12/15/2014 No

Comment: I assume your data are in different cells rather than it is one long entry in a single cell for each row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you need with conditional formatting.

Assume your data is as follows:

```
   A             B             C             D                    E           F
1  Brown, Jean   100 Main St   Richmond VA   This is a long note  12/14/2014  YES
2  Brown, Jean   101 Main St   Richmond VA   This is a long note  12/14/2015  NO
3  Tomas, Bill   2500 Shy Cir  Charlotte CA  This is a long note  12/15/2014  NO
4  Tomas, Bill   2500 Shy Cir  Charlotte CA  This is a new note   12/15/2014  NO
```

For each column you need to set a conditional format formula. Example for `Column A`:

1. Open **Conditional Formatting**
2. Select **New Rule**
3. Select **Use a formula to determine which cells to format**
4. Add the following formula

   `=AND(MOD(ROW(),2)=0,A1<>OFFSET(A1,-1,0))`
5. Now apply for format you want to use as a highlight e..g red color

**Note**: You need to add the formula for each column separately and update the column references. For example, column B formula would be:

`=AND(MOD(ROW(),2)=0,B1<>OFFSET(B1,-1,0))`

The *trick* with this formula is the `MOD(ROW(),2 = 0`. It looks at even rows only (i.e. 2, 4, 6 etc..) and then compares to the previous row. This is important to know depending on how your data is set up in your spreadsheet i.e. in my example I assume your first row is in row 1 and so it is every even row I am comparing to the previous row

Comment: I think I got it to work using =AND(MOD(ROW(),2)=0,A2<>OFFSET(A2,-1,0))